# Problems regarding Pyomo-provided math functions

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to solve a bilevel problem using Pyomo in Python. However, when I try to run the code, I am getting the following error:

"Implicit conversion of Pyomo NumericValue type `mon' to a float is disabled. This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as arguments to one of the Python built-in math module functions when
defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math functions."

In Pyomo's documentation there is no reference to Pyomo-provided functions. I want to know how I can modify the penultimate line of code shown so that model.rn[i,j] meet the integer requirement？

The following is my code:

```python
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.bilevel import *
from pyomo.bilevel.components import SubModel
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

capacity =[150,80, 65]

model = ConcreteModel()
model.sub = SubModel()

model.M=RangeSet(1,3)
model.N=RangeSet(1,12)
model.f= Param(model.M,model.N,within=NonNegativeIntegers,initialize=20)      
model.v= Param(model.M,model.N,within=NonNegativeIntegers)   

model.sub.x = Param(within=Binary)

model.r= Var(model.M,model.N,within=PercentFraction)                     
model.rp= Var(model.M,model.N,within=NonNegativeReals,bounds=(0, 10))     
model.rn = Var(model.M, model.N, within=NonNegativeIntegers)            
model.un= Var(model.M,model.N,within=NonNegativeIntegers)                

for j in range(1,13):
   model.v[1,j] = capacity[0]-model.f[1,j]
   model.v[2,j] = capacity[1]-model.f[2,j]
   model.v[3,j] = capacity[2]-model.f[3,j]

for j in range(1,13):
  for i in range(1,4):
     model.rn[i,j]=floor(model.v[i,j]*model.r[i,j])
     model.un[i,j]=model.v[i,j]-model.rn[i,j]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's tricky to do. As far as I know, it may only work on the values of that pyomo object as model.r is a pyomo object. It is not a problem on a parameter but the variable.
You may want to write out constraints that models the python 'floor' function instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have solved this problem by defining a function.